# Changing default partition table causes restart loop on esp32cam

Tags: esp32

I'm trying to increase app partition size, so that it also supports ota updates. My partitions table looks like this:

```
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,     0x9000,  0x5000,
otadata,  data, ota,     0xe000,  0x2000,
app0,     app,  ota_0,   0x10000, 0x1C0000,
app1,     app,  ota_1,   0x1D0000,0x1C0000,
spiffs,   data, spiffs,  0x3A0000,0x70000,
```

When uploading the code, I see restart loop in logs:

```
rst:0x3 (SW_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
load:0x40078000,len:13232
load:0x40080400,len:3028
entry 0x400805e4
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
```

(Not posting the code, since I believe it's not related to the problem). Thanks for help.

Comment: Author of this post provides a way to increase app partition size: # https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=37092 , but I'm still interested why my solution does not work.

Comment: Are this all the logs, or are there some more logs/warnings/errors?

Comment: @Arco that's all the logs unfortunately.

Comment: In that case it seems that the bootloader crashes, probably due to some problems with the partition table. I'm not sure what exactly causes the problem, but maybe you could try to find which part/value of the partition table causes the crash. For example, by lowering the sizes of the partitions till the rebooting stops.